# Moving product website to company subdomain without losing SEO rankings

Tags: seo, domains, redirects, subdomain, ranking

I manage a website related to a **product**, let's say **www.product.com**.

The company used for years its **company domain** (let's say "www.company.com") as a redirect to www.product.com.

Now we need to refactor the entire website, logo, graphics and so on and we are asking ourselves if the right way to do things is

1) moving actual product.com website to **product.company.com**

or

2) build and let grow **company.com** and when it's completely indexed redirect traffic from old website to subdomain.

product.com isn't an e-commerce and no great "click-to-sell" conversions are made within it: it's just a showcase site.

I think Google will crawl new product.company.com website in days but even managing old link with redirect and 301, I think we can lose a lot of SEO ranking.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Short of doing 301 redirects to preserve any link value, moving any content anywhere is a disruption and will change how a given set of content will perform in search. It is that simple.

Comment: I'm a little lost in this question because the real question is why are you considering moving the product website to the company subdomain product page in the first place?  Whats wrong with refactoring the website where its at now on its own domain?

Comment: @JeffWilbert I assume that a good website structure should be company.com/product and not product.com with company.com redirecting to product.com... am I wrong? Or do you mean to move actual product.com content to domain.com ? Not sure I understood your question, sorry

Comment: Edited: a closing parenthesis changed completely the meaning of the phrase, sorry. I wrote <<The company used for years its company domain (let's say "www.company.com" as a redirect to www.product.com).>> while the meaning was <<The company used for years its company domain (let's say "www.company.com") as a redirect to www.product.com.>>. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) moving actual product.com website to product.company.com or 2) build and let grow company.com and when it's completely indexed redirect traffic from old website to sub-domain.
>
> product.com isn't an e-commerce and no great "click-to-sell" conversions are made within it: it's just a showcase site.

Neither.

Since you say there isn't much to product.com, it doesn't deserve a sub domain or even its domain. You're better off making a sub-folder so your URLs about the products can begin like this:

```
http://company.com/products
```

Then if you want to share details about a specific product, then put a file in the sub-folder so your URL can become something like this:

```
http://company.com/products/cheese.html
```

I'd only consider a sub-domain if there's a massive amount of content relevant to the topic in the sub-domain itself. Since your wanted sub-domain name is products, I'd consider making a fully functional e-commerce site first before putting product information in a sub-domain.

The problem with your idea of....

```
build and let grow company.com and when it's completely indexed
redirect traffic from old website to sub-domain.
```

...is that you're putting mega strain on search engines because you're telling them to record all of your URLs for the site at one location then when the whole site is indexed, then the search engines will slow your server down because when they try accessing the URLs you provided to them at first, they will receive HTTP headers asking them to access new URLs.

This in turn causes search engines to not only make one request to every single URL, but TWO requests. The more requests there are made to your server in one time, the longer it takes for your server to process each one.

Since company.com is your primary site, you're better off keeping it, and not moving content, but if you must, then just move it to a new domain, not a sub-domain.

Also, if you move your site, you're better off making a copy of the website to your new domain and making the new copy not yet indexable, then make changes to the new copy until it is perfect, then setup redirects from the old site to the new site and make the new site indexable again.

The advantage to this is there may be fewer URLs to redirect (especially if you're adding pages in the future), AND the search engines won't have to try to index everything twice.

Comment: Thank your for your articulated reply. In fact the product sold by this company is the main product and constitutes the major economic entry for it. The actual product.com is really articulated (apart from the needing to be refactored and updated). No infos about the company are now in product.com. So I thought it was better to move product site to a subdomain (or a subdir as you suggest) and to keep domain.com the main website. The only thing that worries me is the SEO impact of this operation. Hope I was clear, sorry for my bad English.